# What is a simple method for measuring the physical vibration of a step motor (to STM32) in order to take it to a minimum?

Tags: stepper-motor, stm32f4-discovery, vibration-motor

For a university project we installed a motor that is controlled from a STM32F407G-discovery board through a step motor drive, we experimented with the number of Microsteps options in the drive, and play with the drive/step frequency in the STM32 code to regulate the speed.

Now we are asked to propose a method to quantify the vibration of the motor according to the variation of speed and micro step size.

What would be a simple method to know the vibration of the motor?, we are guessing it has to be very precise because we cannot perceive the vibration changes easily among microsteps.

Thanks in advance to all. this website rocks!

Comment: When you Google for [vibration analysis], what did you find among 1,200,000 hits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Torque is somewhat proportional to both current and acceleration why not monitor current with Back EMF and compare with a ceramic piezo sensors.

I would use a 50mV current shunt with diff amp. and signal conditioner.   3 axis accelerometers are also available in MEMs  and piezoelectric sensors with the latter that requires special charge amplification.

> But what vibration is of interest? Full spectrum or just acoustic?
>    If acoustic, then this demands an audio spectrum filter for signal conditioning.

Some noises are related to bearings and frame structure that are harmonics of the spectrum of acceleration. Amplification or Q values of 10 are quite common at mechanical resonance. Structure rigidity analysis and possibly a modal analysis ( 3axis accelerometer impact transfer function) is also useful if you have access to this specialized test equipment.

Since microstepping also reduces torque, that is also a significant tradeoff with performance.

THere may also be magnetostiction noise with high current rise times so a piezo device with 1D , 2D or 3D into a Spectrum Analyzer is quite practical.

Most mechanical stepper buzz noises are due to the motor operating at a sub harmonic of the system resonance.  This can be minimized by tuning and optimizing the coefficients for stepper ( max acceleration, max velocity , max current, holding current, mm/step or deg/step)

If you do not have direct control of these physical values for quick programmable tests such as using an Arduino CNC shield with GCode flash installed and GCode Panel GUI for Windows and have easy access to driver constants and simple script language . Constants are stored  $xx parameters for X , Y and Z if needed.  When I made my 1st CNC gantry, I wrote a simple GCode test programs to do a "Butterfly seek" which oscillated back and forth with incremental short step seek lengths and changing direction like 1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,.. then see if repositioning the gantry start position had any effect.  Eventually I was able to reduce noise by using full steps and get max speed and acceleration to an acceptable noise level.

Lastly, I have found some small stepper motors that are very quiet on half steps even in an office environment (-60dBA). THis was 35 yrs ago in products from Japan.  They had a rotary oil-filled viscous damper with brass disc inside a clear plastic case attached to the shaft and it also reduced the settling time and overshoot.

Answer (score 1):

What you are being asked to investigate is the settling time (impacted by mechanical resonances in the stepper) for steps.

I suggest you read section 4.3 of [Stepper motors: A guide to theory and practice](https://books.google.com/books?id=mwDCORmy6u0C). It's somewhat older but has an excellent coverage of the topic.

What you are looking for is a way to measure the settling time (you should think about this once you understand) for the various steps. 
The worst resonance is when full stepping and it gets progressively less as you increase the micro-stepping ratio. There are downsides to micro-stepping of course and loss of step torque is the most apparent.

[image]

For full and half steps you can use viscous and magnetic dampers to reduce the oscillation, but micro-stepping is far superior if you can tolerate the torque dropoff.

To see this applied you could start with the [Trinamic Motion Control paper](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Solutions/White_papers/Audio_Turntable/TRINAMIC_Motion_Control_-_Enabling_Ultimate_Fidelity_with_Advanced_Motion_Control.pdf) on using a micro-step motor for linear arm positioning. They give a good explanation of the algorithmic processes used to achieve very low resonance in a linear tone arm.